# How should I apply the same formatting to a list of dataframes in R?

Tags: r, plyr

[Here is what I've done so far.](http://www.dinkypage.com/181773) So, that's basically grabbing some tables off the internet using XML, putting them into a list of dataframes and then some mess trying (and failing) to format them in an efficient and consistent way.

I can't work out how to apply the same changes to all of the dataframes. I think I need to use llply, but I can't get it right. Overall I am trying to achieve:

- Column names all legitimate R names using make.names, then use the
  str_replace_all towards the end of the file to strip all non-alpha
  characters so the names are the same
- Next I want to remove all but the first four columns from all of the dataframes
- Then I want to add a column with the title for each book. I guess I'll have to do this manually.
- Finally, I want to do an rbind to join all of the dataframes together

What's really got me stumped is how to apply the same transformations to each dataframe in the list such as modifying their column names and cutting off rows. Is llply the right tool for the job? How do I use it?

So far the most I've been able to achieve is turning my list of dataframes into a list of vectors with the right names. I believe this is because when I tried using names() it returned the vector of correct names, rather than a dataframe with the correct names. This was my attempt:

```
tlist <- llply(tabs, function(x) as.data.frame(str_replace_all(make.names(names(x)), "[^[:alpha:]]", "")))
```

I don't think I'm a million miles away here, but I can't think how to get it to return the full df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
f <- function(x)
{
 y <- x[,1:4]
 names(y) <- str_replace_all(make.names(names(y)), "[^[:alpha:]]", "")
 y
}

result <- rbind.fill(llply(tabs, f))
```

EDIT: following @baptiste, this may be better:

```
result <- ldply(tabs, f)
```